# Bind Custom List to Gridview using javascript in sharepoint designer

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

**This is my javascript code to bind**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function BindGridView() {
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "AllItems.aspx/PPB",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
     for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++)
   {
     $("#grv1").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].Name + 
                       "</td> <td>" + data.d[i].age + 
                       "</td> <td>" + data.d[i].city +"</td></tr>");
         }
       }
      })
  }
```

**This is Design Code**

```
<body onload="BindGridView();">

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grv1">

</asp:GridView>
</form>

</body>
```

I have already created custom list called PPB in sharepoint with 3 columns, and that list i want to bind to the gridview using javascript or jquery and should be displayed on pranav.aspx.

Want Help...Thank you.!

I have tried but its not working..

Answer (score 0):

After going through your code, I have found that, in the "URL" you are mentioning it like: "AllItems.aspx/PPB". This is incorrect. You can not mention the sharepoint list in the above format.

The "url" specifies the page url and function name of a web method at code behind. So, you shall mention url like :"codebehind.aspx/GetitemsfromPPB"

codebehind.aspx: This is the aspx page conatining the web method to return collection of items from your PPB List

GetitemsfromPPB: "GetitemsfromPPB()" this is the method containing the logic/code to get all items you want to bind.

For reference, please follow the below link.

http://www.aspdotnet-sharepoint.com/2013/05/how-to-bind-data-to-gridview-with.html

I do not know, if we can get data directly from list in the format you have mentioned, if that is the functionality you would like to achieve. As far as I know, you  shall write  your logic in a webmetod to get data. Please let me know for further queries. :)

-Bhargav